# Find all $k$ such that there are infinitely many positive integers $a$ such that $a(a+k) + k$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, motivation

> Problem:
> For a given positive integer $k$, we call an integer $n$ a $k$-number if both of the following
> conditions are satisfied:
> (i) The integer $n$ is the product of two positive integers which differ by $k$.
> (ii) The integer $n$ is $k$ less than a square number.
> Find all $k$ such that there are infinitely many -numbers.
> (BMO2 2022)

> Solution: Note that $n$ is a $k$-number if and only if the equation
> $n = m^2 − k = r(r + k)$ has solutions in integers $m, r$ with $k \geq 0$.
> The right-hand equality can be rewritten as $k^2 − 4k = (2r + k)^2 − (2m)^2$
> ,
> so $k$-numbers correspond to ways of writing $k^2 − 4k$ as a difference of two squares, $N^2 − M^2$
> with $N > r$ and $M$ even (which forces $N$ to have the same parity as $k$).
> Any non-zero integer can only be written as a difference of two squares in finitely many ways
> (because each gives a factorisation, and a number has only finitely many factors).
> If $k \neq 4$ then $k^2 − 4k \neq 0$, and as a result, if $k \neq 4$ then there are only finitely many $k$-numbers.
> Conversely, if $k = 4$ then setting $m = r + 2$ for $r \geq 0$ shows that there are infinitely many
> $4$-numbers.

"so $k$-numbers correspond to ways of writing $k^2 − 4k$ as a difference of two squares" - how does this work?
Also, is there any motivation for doing this, or is the difference of squares just a very common method to prove there does not exist an infinite amount of something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as it says,  $m^2 - k = r(r+k)$ is equivalent to $$k^2 - 4 k = k^2 - 4 (m^2 - r(r+k)) = k^2 + 4rk + 4 r^2 - 4 m^2 = (2r+k)^2 - (2m)^2$$
which says that $k^2 - 4 k$ is the difference of two squares.
The point is that writing something as the difference of two squares, say $x = a^2 - b^2$, tells you that $x = (a-b)(a+b)$, and a nonzero integer has only a finite set of factors.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please check my understanding? Since there are finite ways to factorise the difference of squares, there are finite values for m and r, so there are finite values of n.